# Why does Tire Sealent have an Expired Date?

Tags: tire, sealant

My Orange Seal order just dropped in and after a superficial inspection I realised that it has already expired (7/12/23).
I checked my other bottles and they expired two years ago or so.

What could be a reason sealant expires, and what happens if it is too old?

I usually reseal my tires every 6-8 months. If it expires the month I put it in does it still seal properly?

Comment: The distributor I work for went through this about a year or two ago and when we inquired we were told the date on the bottle is the production date, not the expiration date. They also state that it should  have a shelf life of 1 year opened or unopened.

Answer (score 4):

The natural latex one can deteriorate with time. However, this expiration date is not a "Use by". It just says how long the properties "like new" are guaranteed. The latex can get thicker and that may affect the sealing propertiec, but inside the tyre open to the air there it will thicken or dry out much quicker.